# Best way to handle a dynamic form client-side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a dynamic form. It looks like this:

[image]

When "Add destination" is clicked I want to add another section, "Address 3". If "Remove destination" is clicked after that, "Address 3" should be renumbered to "Address 2".

I've done things like this before, but it always feels like a big mess of HTML and JavaScript. I'm trying to figure out the best approach. Here are some possible solutions:

1. Wrap each section in a `<div>`. When "Add destination" is clicked, [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the last section. Loop over each input in the clone, update the `name` and `id` attributes. Wrap the address # in a `<span>` and update that too. Add some more JavaScript to initialize the date and time pickers and validator.
2. Build the entire DOM with JavasScript/jQuery.
3. Put the entire chunk of HTML into a JavaScript string. Use placeholders for IDs, names, and numbers. Use some basic string replacing to increment them as necessary.
4. Use a client-side templating language like [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) that will only be used in one or two places throughout the entire project.

None of the solutions are particularly appealing. How would you approach this problem and why?

Comment: use selection collection array index

Answer (score 1):

this is a quick hack but reliable in most conditions

http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/7pceP/

```
var s = $('.sample'), c= $('.container'), total=1;

$('.Add>a').click(function(){addSample();});


function addSample() {
   var clone = s.first().clone();
   clone.find('.Remove').toggle().click(function(){ rmvSample($(this)); });
   clone.find('.num').text(++total);
   clone.insertBefore(c.children(":last-child"));
}

function rmvSample(x) {
    total--;
    x.parent().remove();
    updateIndex();  
}

function updateIndex(){
    $('.sample').each(function(i){
        $(this).find('.num').text(i+1);
    });
}
```

Comment: That's a lot simpler than I imagined. A few kinks to work out, but a very good start.

Comment: I am impressed you got it..because i am terrible at understanding code , even written by me. :D

Comment: Haha... I had to scratch my head and think about it, but I see what you're doing here :-)

Answer (score 0):

How: You could initialize a global var with value 1 and each time the add click handler is called, the variable is incremented and the name is formed by "Address " + globalCount. Similarly, when the remove destination is clicked, the global count is decremented.

Why: Very little logic, although global variables are not the greatest at times, it reduces other complexity that would arise from other solutions and is pretty elegant.

Other option: When creating the first destination section you could provide it with a data attribute `$(destinationToCreate).data('count', 1).`

I would assume that these destinations sections would be created within some kind of container and that they are of the same structure so that when you're creating a new one something like this would be possible:

```
var newCount = $('#destinationContainer div').last().data('count')++
```

Comment: Yeah...that global counter part is the easy bit. Which method would you use it with though? A bad wad of HTML with string replace? Building the DOM manually with JS? What?

Comment: I see what you're asking. Out of the ones you suggested probably #3 only with variables instead of string replacement. Perhaps a little helper function would simplify the issues. Let me write up what I mean and I'll post it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, what I've done is stuff an entire Twig template into a JavaScript string:

```
var template = {% filter json_encode|raw %}{% include 'bookings/address.twig' %}{% endfilter %};
```

The template contains some [Underscore/lodash template](http://lodash.com/docs#template) variables in it, like `<%- index %>`, which I use in all the IDs and names. Then I render it out as needed:

```
_.template(template,{'index':addressCounter++})
```

This way I can take full advantage of the Twig templating language and use its form builder inside my template. I had briefly contemplated using [Nunjucks](http://jlongster.github.io/nunjucks/) instead of lodash, which is basically just Twig for JavaScript. I figured it might get confusing to use Twig inside of Twig, however, and I didn't want to include a full runtime when all I really need use a few simple variable substitutions.

Seems to be working pretty well so far.